# empty select field for django filters ModelMultipleChoiceFilter with Materialize

Tags: django, python-3.x, materialize, django-filters

I'm using django filters and I have a ModelMultipleChoiceFilter with choices from a queryset, let's say `my_app.MyModel.objects.all()`.

When rendering the the form

```
<form action="" method="get">                           
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}                              
    <div class="right-align">                           
        <input type="submit" class="btn waves-effect"/> 
    </div>                                              
</form>
```

I get in the select field on my page the first entry from the queryset, although it is not selected.

Looking at the source code I see that I get an input field with `value` set to the first entry:

```
<input class="select-dropdown active" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-..." value="FirstEntry" type="text">
```

How can I pass a "None" value to the queryset? Or even better, how can I tell Materialize not to take the first value as a default value (which is not even selected)?

Comment: Try rendering the filter form without materialize. You want to know if the form is either being rendered with a default `value`, or if materialize is somehow selecting the first option. If it's the latter, then this is completely unrelated to django-filter, and you should look to see how you can disable automatic choice selection in materialize.